# 8 bit PictureBox Display Resolution

Tags: c#, image, resolution

I want to create a 8 bit pixel image. I used to draw the image in a picture box.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(8,8);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
PictureBox8Bit.Image = b;
```

So, that code supposed to create an 8 bit pixel image. When i output the image on picture box, i cant see it clearly because its too small. What i want is how to make the picture box resolution to 8 bit, or the image size. So i can see the preview in the picture box.

But when i use the code, the picturebox just show a small dot. Rather than resized to 8 bit for best view.

Thanks.

Comment: Just set the picture box' SizeMode property to Zoom.

Comment: "resized to 8 bit"? That makes no sense. 8 bit is colour quality; it is 100% unrelated to size.

Answer (score 2):

You need to differ between the bitmap *dimension* describing the size of the bitmap in pixels wide and pixels high, and the bitmap *resolution* describing the number of possible colors.

To create a 8-bit Bitmap first read the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx). There you'll find the constructor used in this snippet.

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(w, h, Format8bppIndexed);
```

Where `w` and `h` are the width and height of the image.

Using 8-bit images uses a [ColorPalette](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colorpalette.aspx) making them a bit more complicated to use.